# JS splice not working correctly to remove React Component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, user-interface, splice

My code consists of a parent(Show) and a child(Editable) component. 
Parent contains an array in which Child elements are pushed.I am attaching a screenshot for clarity.

[image]

I am trying remove a Child (an array element) using splice().I am getting correct output on splicing the array. Example as in the screenshot If I am deleting "new" from the array my array arr = [dat2,dat3] but in the front end the last element is getting deleted and it displays dat2,new in the manner shown below.On clicking on make changes I get dat2 and dat3 as required.  I have done splicing using the correct index But it doesn't seem to work corectly in the UI.

Please help. I have tried almost everything:(

I am just forwarding the functions required.

Parent COde:

```
handleMinus(id,idShow){

  this.state.Example=this.props.result.examples
  this.state.Example.splice(id,1);  
  this.props.result.examples=this.state.Example;
  this.setState({create:!this.state.create})


};

    render() { 
    var showExm = this.props.result.examples.map(function(result,index){
            console.log("EditableIntents")
            return <div key={index}><EditableIntents
                                    handleMinus={that.handleMinus}
                                    result={result}
                                    indexEg={index}
                                    indexShowInt={that.props.index}
                                    editExample={that.editExample}/>
                          </div>
            });
    return({showExm});
}
```

Child:

```
render() { 
    return(
      <div>
      <TextField
              defaultValue={this.props.result}
              hintText={this.props.result}
              onChange= {this.changeEg}
              id="editText"
            />
            <span><IconButton id={"aa"+1} onClick={this.handleMinus} iconStyle={{width: 72, height: 72, float: -60}}><span><MinusIcon /> </span></IconButton></span>
            </div>
          )
   }

 handleMinus(){
     console.log(this.props.indexEg);
    console.log("in Grand child:",this.props.result,this.props.indexEg);
    this.props.handleMinus(this.props.indexEg,this.props.indexShowInt)
   }
```

Comment: you need to add unique and persistent keys to your children so that react can reconcile properly.

Comment: I have added key when im creating EditableIntents ( key={index})

Comment: Since React Components are based on pure functions, you should never use `splice` because it mutates the state directly. Instead, make use of `slice` and replace the new piece of sliced state with `setState` method.

Comment: But using slice doesn't give me a new updated array. And even if i try to use it, it will just return me the value which is to be deleted not the one's left after removing the value.

Comment: you should avoid using `index` as `key`, because if you will remove item with `index == 1` then u will still be left with array of indexes 0 and 1, but you are supposed to delete item with key 1.... this will cause problem

Comment: Initially I was using key= index+1 but that dint help either.

Comment: i guess you havent understanded yet so ill say it again. DON'T USE INDEX AT ALL, use something that is unique to each element of the array or something like lodash/unique

Comment: Thanks @DayanMorenoLeon it worked. I used uuid.

Comment: good stuff. keep it up :)

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with your index may be

Child:

```
render() {

    return(
      <div>
      <TextField
              defaultValue={this.props.result}
              hintText={this.props.result}
              onChange= {this.changeEg}
              id="editText"
            />

/* I have just changed here your onClick function */

            <span><IconButton id={"aa"+1} onClick={() => this.handleMinus(index)} iconStyle={{width: 72, height: 72, float: -60}}><span><MinusIcon /> </span></IconButton></span>


            </div>
          )

   }

/*and here I have added parameter */

 handleMinus(keyid){
     console.log(this.props.indexEg);
    console.log("in Grand child:",this.props.result,this.props.indexEg);
    this.props.handleMinus(keyid,this.props.indexShowInt)
   }

Also you should define "this.state.Example" as array

handleMinus(id,idShow){

this.state.Example = [];

  this.state.Example=this.props.result.examples
  this.state.Example.splice(id,1);  
  this.props.result.examples=this.state.Example;
  this.setState({create:!this.state.create})
};
```

It may help you.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't help. I am getting the same result , Wrong result at the UI.  Also by onClick={() => this.handleMinus(index)} You ment onClick={() => this.handleMinus(this.props.indexEg)} right?

Comment: It seems you are not getting correct id in this.state.Example.splice(id,1); right?

Comment: I am getting the correct id.. for "dat2" i am getting 0 for "new" 1 and as required. Thats why i am getting the correct array after splicing. But this new array is not getting displayed correctly. On each minus I am gettiing correct array but at the UI last element is getting deleted. Though in array and backend it is still present.

Comment: Then direct splice the result.examples like this.props.result.examples.splice(id,1), and remove unnecessary this.state.Example defined variable